# flexigrid on height auto, hide/show feature doesn't work

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Whenever I set the height to 'auto' the hide/show feature next to each field header doesn't work anymore, the menu doesn't open on the arrow click.
However if I hard code a height it works properly.
I saw a possible solution here suggesting to automatically resize on load but still does not seem to do the trick.
http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/issues/detail?id=74#c3